# Expected ';' before '{' token in ine 10

Tags: c

I am new to programming and this is what I am getting when I try to compile this program. Can you please help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()

{

    int Fahrenheit;

    int Celcius;

    int choice;

    int temperature;

    printf ( "What do you want to do? (1/2) \n 1. Fahrenheit to Celcius \n. 2. Celcius to Fahrenheit \n. "

    if ( 1 )

{

   printf ( "Enter Fahrenheit \n." )

   scanf ( "%d", &Fahrenheit );

   Celcius=( Fahrenheit-32 )*5/9;

   print( "The temperature in Celcius is %d \n", Celcius );

}

   else ( 2 )

{

    printf ( "Enter celcius\n" );

    scanf ( "%d", &Celcius );

    Fahrenheit=Celcius*((9/5)+32);

    printf ( "The temperature in Fahrenheit is %d \n, Fahrenheit );

    }

  }
```

Comment: You're missing closing `)` and `;` in a few places.

Comment: `if(1)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: And `else (2)` doesn't either.

Comment: Compiler output shows which line is causing the problem

Comment: You'll run into problems with integer arithmetic on things like this: `Celcius=( Fahrenheit-32 )*5/9;`. Like `Celcius` will always be 0.

Comment: Questions caused by simple typographical errors are not deemed unsuitable here.

Comment: I would also suggest reading the Stack Overflow help > on-topic particularly category "2" before posting further questions. This will help avoid large numbers of downvotes in the future http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of all compilation errors I found.

The first problem is on this line:

`printf ( "What do you want to do? (1/2) \n 1. Fahrenheit to Celcius \n. 2. Celcius to Fahrenheit \n. "`

You're missing a closing parentheses and a semicolon.

Another is here:

`printf ( "Enter Fahrenheit \n." )`

you missed a semicolon at the end.

Another problem is in this line:

`else ( 2 )`

`else` doesn't have a condition block like `if()`, so `( 2 )` is treated like the statement that needs to execute in case the condition in the `if` your `else` belongs to isn't satisfied. However, it misses a ';' at the end, hence the error. The block enclosed by `{ }` doesn't relate to your `else` at all.

Here's another:

`printf ( "The temperature in Fahrenheit is %d \n, Fahrenheit );` you're missing a closing `"` in your string literal.

Generally, even if you correct all of these mistakes, your code still will not do what you expect it to. I suggest you sit down with a good book or beginner's tutorial on programming before trying to code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, an expected ';' error means you are missing a semi-colon.
If you look at line 10, you are missing the semi-colon after if(1) and after the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

After `else` should NOT be ( 2 ). Else has not additional conditions, and is just the optional part of `if`

Answer (score 0):

you need ; after printf on line 10